# TortoiseSVN commit shortcut

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I find it tedious when everytime I need to commit a file.The process goto windows explorer window, right click directory, then click 'Commit'... and then the tortoisesvn commit window.

Anyone know of any shortcut to do this? Maybe press a keyboard shortcut to commit instead of having to right click directory then click commit?

Thank you for saving my productivity!

Comment: would clarify that I'm using Windows 7.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See the chapter "[automating TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html#tsvn-automation-basics)" in the docs.

You could create a shortcut to TortoiseProc.exe and add the command line params there, e.g.:

```
TortoiseProc.exe /command:commit /path:"path\to\your\workingcopy"
```

Answer (score 7):

I use [autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to do this.

Here are some instructions if you want to use it:

- [Download](http://www.autohotkey.com/download/) and install autohotkey.
- Put the following text in a text file called *TortoiseSVN.ahk*:

> ```
> ; Change your hotkey here
> +`::
>
> Run TortoiseProc.exe /command:commit /path:"<path-to-your-working-copy>"
>
> return
> ```

- The hotkey in this script is set to *shift + tilde*.  Look at the [autohotkey docs](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/) to help you [choose a different hotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm).
- Make sure you put the path to your SVN working directory in the script.
- Put the text file into your *startup* directory so that it will run when windows restarts.
- To run the script now, just double-click the text file (providing you have already installed autohotkey).

You should now be able to use *shift + tilde* (or whatever your choosen hotkey) to invoke the TortoiseSVN commit dialog.

Answer (score 1):

You can use svn through the command-line, the way that I guess most linux-type-people do: http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download/

If you happen to have a command-line window open most of the time (e.g. for running Ant tasks or something) then this might be a faster way. You would just type:

```
svn commit
```

or even

```
svn ci
```

(the `ci` stands for "check in")

Answer (score 1):

If you're in visual studio, you can use [AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/)

Comment: @Mendy - It does what it's supposed to - it's definitely not $49 worse.

Answer (score 1):

Extending on Stefan's answer, I found one of the easiest ways (or so I think) to use shortcut keys to commit.

[QTTabBar](http://qttabbar.sourceforge.net/) (sort of like an add-on for Explorer) has the ability to execute any application passing arguments.

The arguments can be selected folder, selected file etc.

I wrote a [blog post](http://techbystep.blogspot.com/2011/06/commit-using-shortcut-key-in.html) describing how to use this functionality to commit/update or do just about anything.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use window explorer Shortcuts.
Just open code folder in explorer and use below:

```
Commit: alt + F + C
update: alt + F + U
Check for updates: alt + F + T + F
```

So you can press above keyboard shortcuts to commit instead of having to right click directory then click commit. These shortcuts are quite handy, since you do not need to create any batch or script file.